# Sharepoint Connector Not Showing Up in Azure Logic App

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps, connector

I am trying to add the Sharepoint connector in my Azure Logic App, but it is not showing up Under Choose an operation when I enter **sharepoint** as the search term. Does anyone know why this connector is currently unavailable?

[image: Sharepoint Connector Not Showing Up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please expand the search results. It's there,
[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. I found it after expanding the search results like you suggested.